# Three.js: Drag Panorama Smoothly with Easing

Tags: javascript, three.js, easing, tween.js

I am using this demo as a base for my 6 cube panorama project: https://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_geometry_panorama

Mouse events manage the dragging functionality. I want to apply easing so the panorama cube is smoothly following the mouse. I do know that easing is a difference of distance between current element position and mouse coordinates divided by some integer (eg. 5). In example above, I find hard time figuring out how to apply it. Here is the code sample:

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    isUserInteracting = true;
    onPointerDownPointerX = event.clientX;
    onPointerDownPointerY = event.clientY;
    onPointerDownLon = lon;
    onPointerDownLat = lat;
}
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
    if ( isUserInteracting === true ) {
        lon = ( onPointerDownPointerX - event.clientX ) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLon;
        lat = ( event.clientY - onPointerDownPointerY ) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLat;
    }
}
function update() {
    if ( isUserInteracting === false ) { lon += 0.1; }
    lat = Math.max( - 85, Math.min( 85, lat ) );
    phi = THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 - lat );
    theta = THREE.Math.degToRad( lon );
    target.x = 500 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );
    target.y = 500 * Math.cos( phi );
    target.z = 500 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );
    camera.lookAt( target );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

In `onDocumentMouseMove` there is already some calculation done in difference of points which does not allow me to achieve successful easing.

Note: I would prefer using own code rather than additional libraries which handle easing.

Comment: in update record `lastMousePosition`, subtract current mouse position, divide by some smoothing amount, use that as the offset amount. call `update` everyframe with `requestAnimation`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to add damping to your panorama is to use `OrbitControls`. You can use a pattern like so:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 90, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100 );
camera.position.z = 0.01;

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.enableZoom = false;
controls.enablePan = false;
controls.enableDamping = true;
```

Then, in you animation loop:

```
requestAnimationFrame( animate );

controls.update(); // required when damping is enabled; otherwise, not required

renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

Experiment with the three.js `webgl_panorama_cube.html` example.

three.js r.89

Comment: Thank you. I looked at it and I think I prefer full control of esing calculations as well as mouse. So OrbitsControls.js dependency is not ideal. Is there a harder way to achieve easing?

Comment: There is always a harder way.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There's also this code built off OrbitControls: https://gist.github.com/Samsy/f8c2a62e41519a404ee8617f88234a7b